# If $m_1=m_2z$ and $n_1=n_2z$ where $z=\operatorname{lcm} (m_1,n_1)$, then $\operatorname{lcm}(m_2,n_2)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility

I know if $z=\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,n_1)$, then

(1) $n_1|z$ and $m_1|z$

(2) for every integer $k$, if $n_1|k$ and $m_1|k$, then $z|k$

and I know that $m_2|m_1$ and $n_2|n_1$ but I dont know what is the next?

Comment: Don't you mean $\gcd$, not  $lcm$?

Comment: The problem said it is lcm, not gcd.

Comment: If it's $lcm$, them that implies that $m_2=n_2=1$, since $lcm$ is the least common multiple?

Comment: would you prove it please? , i know another way to solve it within lemma:if m>0, lcm(ma,mb) = mxlcm(a,b). But my teacher said not to use it.

Comment: No, I think that it is actually a typo.. How can $z|m_1$ is $z$ is the least common mutiple? That makes no sense/..

Comment: yeah i think so, from $z=lcm(m_1,n_1)$, we got $m_1|z$ and $n_1|z$, from $m_1=m_2z$ and $n_1=n_2z$, we got $z|m_1$ and $z|n_1$, it isn't possible except one case, $m_1=m_2=n_1=n_2=1=z$. So, what can i conclude? it is typo or the only that one case?

Comment: I think it's a typo. The question would make no sense otherwise.

Comment: can you prove it if it is gcd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1).If $z=\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,n_1)$, then $m_1|z$ and $n_1|z$ by the definition of. $z$ is the common multiplier of $m_1$ and $n_1$.

(2).We prove by contradiction: If $k$ is not divided by $z$, then by division algorithm, $k=zd+r$ where $0<r<z$, by hypothesis that $m_1|k=zd+r$ and $n_1|k=zd+r$ and also $m_1|z$ and $n_1|z$, so $m_1|r$ and $n_1|r$, this lead to r is the common multiplier of $m_1$ and $n_1$and $r<z$, which contradict that z is the least common multiplier.

Comment: Thank You Lee, it helps me!

Comment: You're welcome!